# Getting error when trying to disconnect users from database

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog, administration

I am a GIS administrator using ArcMap 10.8 and I need to occasionally disconnect users from my company's enterprise database (RDBMS is Oracle 19c) so maintenance can be done on it via the geodatabase administration window. However, when I tried to disconnect users, I get an error message saying "Underlying DBMS error [no data found]. I am trying to do this after hours, when everyone else has left for the day. What I find weird is that there are still connections to the database, even when the users have their computers off, but that is besides the point.

How do I disconnect users via the geodatabase administrator without getting said error?

Also worth noting that I tested this on myself using my nonadmin account to connect to the database and trying to disconnect it via my admin account and got the same error.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the RDBMS in use, and whether the  "admin account" has the necessary permission. Users whose computers are off are not connected, just have unclosed connection records in corrupted metadata.

Comment: RDBMS is Oracle 19c. Not sure how to check permissions as I don't see that option when I right click the database in arccatalog

Comment: In Oracle, the privilege is "ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION" (DBA has it).

Comment: Got it to work. Thank you!